# Strange bug that will mess up counting of layers and shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've some problems with the counting of layers, that is frustrating. When I start a new Photoshop document and add some layers to it, it will work correctly. But especially when I have 6x duplicated a group, the counting of the layers will be from for example Rectangle 4 to Rectangle 505. It's very strange and it will only appears when there are a specific amount of duplicated groups are in the document.

For me I've one group that consists out of 2 groups inside and in one of them 2 other groups. When I duplicate the highest group it will count from where it remained. But after the sixth copy of the group it will mess up the counting of the layers.

Anyone else has this very strange bug in Photoshop CC 2017? And are there some fixes for this?

Casper